# Which file gradle.properties is higher priority?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle.properties

I have local and global gradle.properties, the global one is needed to configure the proxy, but it also contains other parameters, wondering what happens if for the same settings you specify different values, which of the files will be in priority or maybe they are How do they merge?

my global gradle.properties

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=hostname
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password

org.gradle.parallel=false
```

my local gradle.properties

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M
```

For example, which `org.gradle.parallel` will be used?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [Gradle properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties), the `gradle.properties` files are applied in the following order:

1. `gradle.properties` in project root directory.
2. `gradle.properties` in `GRADLE_USER_HOME` directory.
3. system properties, e.g. when `-Dgradle.user.home` is set on the command line.

Because the properties in `GRADLE_USER_HOME` are applied after the ones in the project root, they override the ones defined in the project. Assuming that with global you mean the one in the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` directory and local the one in your project root, your value for `org.gradle.parallel` will be `false`.

Comment: great explanation. 

Personally I am not totally in agreement with the order between the  local gradle.properties  file  to a project and the global gradle.properties file. 

I think  it would  make more sense    for  the global parameters   oto be verwritten by the local parameters to a project ...

Comment: Be sure to read the link shared on the Post, the order is different about presentation and has a new item